# How to select elements where id is not

Tags: javascript

I have multiple divs, and I would like to give a style at one when I click on it. And delete the style of all others divs it when I click on one other div.

To add style, this works :

`document.getElementById(i).classList.add('border-blue-400', 'border-b-2', 'border-l-4');`

The answer has been removed, I dont know why but I did this :

```
 let docs = document.querySelectorAll(':not([id^='+i+'])')
        for(let doc of docs)
        {
            doc.classList.remove('border-blue-400');
        }
```

and it works

thanks

To remove it, I tried this but it does not work :

`document.querySelectorAll(':not([id^='+i+'])').classList.remove('border-blue-400');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an event listener to each element using for example a class, when an element in the class is clicked, the function will go over every element in the class and remove the style you defined.

By passing the clicked element to the function, we can then use `target.id` to check if the element we are going over has the same ID as the element we clicked on, in which case we apply a different style.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".div").forEach(div => addEventListener("click", (element) => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.div').forEach(div => {
        if(div.id != element.target.id) {
            div.style.border = "10px solid green";
        }
        else {
            div.style.border = "10px solid black";
        }
    });
}));
```

```css
.div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 10px solid green;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="div" id="1"></div>
    <div class="div" id="2"></div>
    <div class="div" id="3"></div>
</body>
</html>
```